# Tortoise SVN update working copy with Active

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In my SVN repo browser I have multiple items (folders).  I have two that are important, the first is CM_Active which corresponds to my Active project.  This is the project that is live.  I also have CM_Working which corresponds to my working project.  I have made changes to my Active copy, how do I copy over the Active changes to update my working copy?  I am new to SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Using TortoiseSVN - open the folder containing your working copy, select all files, right click and select 'SVN Update'.

Via the CLI - use command `svn update PATH`

Comment: I do not see 'SVN Update' I see 'Update item to revision' is that the same thing?

Comment: You could use 'Update item to revision' and select 'HEAD', that will update you to the latest revision. There's a quicker way though, with 'Update'. If you select TortoiseSVN >> Update does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) book.

If Active is a branch of Working, the you should use [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html). If Active is not a branch of Working the I highly recommend making it a branch, as then it is easier to manage, because then it will be easier to see exactly what changed since the last merge.

The TortoiseSVN documentation is [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html), with the documentation on merging [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).